# Ways to embed a version protocol number in every request in REST?

Tags: web-services, rest, ios5, soa, restful-architecture

When developing apps, your server and your iPhone evolve and not always back-compatibility is possible.
I guess adding a protocol version number in every request should do the trick (instead of, let's say another web service for protocol version). 
Amazon do it in every request (here a sample):
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=269876
So, when the app is too old for the current protocol, it shows a message blocking the app and asking the users for an update. Otherwise, customers with an old app will see an app that doesn't work very well. That's not good.

My question is: How do you implement a similar versioning schema into a JSON reply without interfering the parser, object mapping and entity mapping? Any suggestion?

Perhaps there is another schema like passing an app version in the headers every request, and if error, the server returns and error message like (from twitter):
{"errors":[{"message":"Sorry, that page does not exist","code":34}]}

I'd like to know how do you solve this problem.
Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can version your API using the media-type. For instance, if your media-type is `application/vnd.ricardo+json` and you need to make a change that is not backwards compatible,  you would create an `application/vnd.ricardo-v2+json` media type.

New version of the app will `Accept` the `application/vnd.ricardo-v2+json` media-type and get the new content. Old versions of the app will continue to `Accept` the `application/vnd.ricardo+json` and will never see the incompatible change.

When you want to retire old versions of the app, simply have requests that only accept `application/vnd.ricardo+json` return `406 Not Acceptable`. You can then use this in you app to trigger logic to prompt the user to upgrade.

If (for whatever reason) you need to allow the app to support multiple versions of the server you can have it `Accept` `application/vnd.ricardo-v2+json, application/vnd.ricardo+json; q=0.5`. In this situation, the server will respond with `application/vnd.ricardo-v2+json` content if it can and `application/vnd.ricardo+json` otherwise.

You could use this to give you greater control over the "release" of a new feature. For instance you could release and update for the app, use request statistics to determine when a sufficient number of users have upgraded. You can then co-ordinate releasing the new feature by flipping a feature toggle on your servers and doing a marketing effort at the same time.